# Encoding ENUM data type in struct for EIP712

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, struct, eip712, enum

I have a struct.

```
struct Order {
        uint256 price;
        uint256 quantity;
        OrderType orderType;
    }

    enum OrderType {
        BUY,
        SELL
    }
```

Question is, how should I create typehash for EIP712 in solidity. I'm doing this,

```
    bytes32 public constant _ORDER_TYPEHASH =
        keccak256(
            "Order(uint256 price,uint256 quantity,OrderType orderType)"
        );
```

And to create signature for test using ethers.js I'm creating type like this

```
        Order: [
          {
            name: "price",
            type: "uint256",
          },
          {
            name: "quantity",
            type: "uint256",
          },
          {
            name: "orderType",
            type: "uint8",
          },
        ],
```

I'm using `uint8` for OrderType as ethers.js don't know what `enum` is. The signature generated from signing this is invalid.

When I remove  `OrderType` from `Order` struct and from `_ORDER_TYPEHASH` then signature generated is valid.

Now I do not know I'm doing wrong encoding in solidity or in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be with the encoding of the data that is being signed.

In your Solidity code, you have defined the `OrderType` enum as `BUY` and `SELL`. However, in your JavaScript code, you are using `uint8` to represent the `OrderType`. This can cause a mismatch in the encoding of the `orderType` field, leading to an invalid signature.

To ensure that the encoding is consistent between the Solidity and JavaScript code, you can use the `toNumber()` method in ethers.js to convert the `OrderType` enum to a `uint8`. Here's how you can update your JavaScript code:

```
Order: [
  {
    name: "price",
    type: "uint256",
  },
  {
    name: "quantity",
    type: "uint256",
  },
  {
    name: "orderType",
    type: "uint8",
    value: (type) => type.orderType === "BUY" ? 0 : 1,
  },
],
```

In this updated code, the `value` field is a function that converts the `OrderType` enum to a `uint8` value based on its string representation.

With this change, the encoding of the `orderType` field should match between the Solidity and JavaScript code, resulting in a valid signature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro, but it did not work. I just hard coded 0 to value field. wrong signature again.